# When does the player choose to apply effort to increase damage?

Tags: attack-roll, numenera

In Numenera, players can apply effort to increase their chance to hit with an attack and/or to increase the damage of the attack.

Thus far, my group has been playing that they can apply the effort to increase damage after making the attack roll and thus knowing that it has connected. I get the feeling however that maybe the players would need to declare before rolling what effort is being applied to the attack and/or damage for the attack, but I can't find a clear ruling in the book. Which scenarios correct?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Before you make the roll**.

It's very easy to miss the rule, as it is on **page 21**, and rarely spoken again through the book.

> You don’t have to apply Effort if you don’t want to. If you choose to
>   apply Effort to a task, you must do it before you attempt the roll—you
>   can’t roll first and then decide to apply Effort if you rolled poorly.

Comment: Also falls under the "use logic" meta-rule: if you want to put effort into something, you'll have to decide before you do it, not after.

Comment: @Raphael I was using that logic for all other rolls, but my question was specifically about the increase to damage, which isn't a roll. Also, I know I'm almost a year late replying, but I've just seen the comment now.

Comment: @ConorPender How is that any different? You make an effort; maybe you feint to get past the defense more easily (= lower difficulty), or you aim at a weak spot or hit harder (= more damage). Either way, it's part of the same action, and you have to decide before you start it. That is, the player has to decide before the roll.

Comment: @Raphael That was how I ruled it too, but my players disagreed. I know that as the GM I could just overrule them, but I decided to ask the question and look for other opinions(or rules references).

Comment: @ConorPender Well, the rules are pretty clear as ShadowKras quotes them: *before* the roll. Since hitting and damage are the same task in the Cypher system, there is no room in between to do anything. I was just trying to offer logic that explains this.